# Add data inside < > of an html element using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to add data (that is not a class, id or value) inside the < > selectors of a div?

Say I have something like this

```
<div class="selection">normal html</div>
```

That I need to turn into something like this, inserting a data-use-type="STRING" value:

```
<div class="selection" data-use-type="STRING">normal html</div>
```

I can't edit the html directly, so javascript would be the perfect solution for it. And I know how to use the append function, but it does not work for what I want, I think... Can prepend work that way?

Comment: RTD: https://api.jquery.com/attr & https://api.jquery.com/data. Use the latter unless you explicitly need the attribute to appear in the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure JavaScript solution

```js
let div = document.getElementsByClassName("selection")[0]
div.setAttribute("data-use-type","String")
console.log(div)
```

```html
<div class="selection">normal html</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set properties on the [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) of the element.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.dataset.useType = "STRING";
console.log(div.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="selection">normal html</div>
```